# MoPub cannot find com.mopub.mobileads.VastVideoInterstitial

Tags: android, android-studio, mopub, vast

I have integrated the full SDK from MoPub, including copying over the necessary adapters into the source for my MoPub module.

However, when I request an ad from MoPub, I keep getting an error:

```
Couldn't locate or instantiate custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.VastVideoInterstitial.
```

The problem is that `VastVideoInterstitial` is most definitely included, so I am baffled as to why MoPub cannot find it. My `AndroidManifext.xml` includes all the activities I could find for the MoPub module:

```
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
    <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.BaseVideoPlayerActivity"  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

What am I missing here to show VAST video interstitials? I could turn them off in MoPub, but this seems to be a poor option as it would cause the eCPM for my app to drop.

How can I solve this issue in Android?

Comment: Hey Adam,

Are you using proguard in your project?
If you are using proguard, you may have to keep the custom event by declaring it in your proguard file.
https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Proguard

If that custom event is being excluded by proguard, your project may not be able to find the specific file, returning the error you see.

Are you seeing regular interstitials working fine or are neither video or static interstitials showing?

Edward

Comment: Regular interstitials work fine, it just seems that anything with a VAST tag isn't working. I am not using proguard for these builds - just the debug builds.

Comment: 1. Have you made sure that VastVideoInterstitial.java is included in your project in your com.mopub.mobileads folder? 2. Have you declared the permissions as outlined here? https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Interstitial-Integration 3. If this doesn't work, I would compare your integration with the sample app on the main page of their github for their Android SDK here: https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this using the old standby of **Clean** and **Rebuild** in Android Studio.

MoPub seems to be generating some odd errors recently in AS. We've only been able to solve these errors by a combination of:

- Clean and rebuild
- Restart AS
- Restart the machine